# Mocha test is timing out on MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, mean

I am working on a MEAN stack application (using a tutorial for guidance) and I have run into an issue with one of my tests. When I run the below mocha test it times out. I've tried extending the timer but to no avail. I have another test that is almost identical but for a different route. I checked my api file to make sure that I have the correct urls. Not sure what is happening here.

- express v4.12.3
- mocha v2.2.4
- gulp-mocha v2.0.1
- superagent v1.2.0
- gulp v3.9.0
- node v5.1.0

The code is :

```
 describe('Transaction API', function() {
    it('can load a transaction by id', function(done) {
        // Create a single transaction
        var TRANSACTION_ID = '001';
        var transaction = {
            name: 'LG2 G4',
            _id: TRANSACTION_ID,
            amount: 300
        };

        Transaction.create(transaction, function(error, doc) {
            assert.ifError(error);
            var url = URL_ROOT + '/transactions/id/' + TRANSACTION_ID;
            superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                assert.ifError(error);
                var result;
                // And make sure we got the LG G4 back
                assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                    result = JSON.parse(res.text);
                });

                assert.ok(result.transaction);
                assert.equal(result.transaction._id, TRANSACTION_ID);
                assert.equal(result.transaction.name, 'LG2 G4');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my route in app.js

```
api.get('/transactions/id/:id', wagner.invoke(function(Transactions) {
        return function(req, res) {
      Transactions.findOne({ _id: req.params.id },
        handleOne.bind(null, 'transactions', res));
        };
}));

function handleOne(property, res, error, result) {
 if (error) {
    return res.
      status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
      json({ error: error.toString() });
 }

 if (!result) {
        return res.
      status(status.NOT_FOUND).
      json({ error: 'Not found' });
 }

var json = {};
json[property] = result;
res.json(json);
}
```

For some reason this works just fine.

```
api.get('/category/id/:id', wagner.invoke(function(Category) {
    return function(req, res) {
      Category.findOne({ _id: req.params.id },
        handleOne.bind(null, 'category', res));
        };
}));
```

Comment: can you check if your callback passed to `superagent.get` is called? try logging something inside the callback.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg I get this '{"error":"CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"001\" at path \"_id\""}'

Comment: Yes, you need to pass Object Id in the `Transactions.findOne`.  Since `_id` is of type ObjectId. you need to covert `req.params.id` to ObjectId.

Comment: Can you tell me why my above edit works but this doesnt?

Comment: by default, mongo generates _id fields which is of type ObjectId. since you are defining your own _id which is of type string and you are passing `req.params.id` of type string, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error was in my Transactions model. In the category model I had identified

```
_id : {
    type : String
},
```

But had not done the same in the transactionSchema.